# Jenkins Helm format for master.JCasC.configScripts

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, kubernetes-helm, jenkins-job-dsl

I have values.yaml that is working perfectly.

I would like to add Jcasc Config Yml to automatically add pipelines but cannot find the format for the values.yml file.

Currently I have below and would like to reference Jenkins.yaml

```
JCasC:
enabled: true
pluginVersion: 1.35
configScripts:
  welcome-message: |
    jenkins:
      systemMessage: Welcome to our CI\CD server.  This Jenkins is configured and managed 'as code'.
```

What should I put for the `configScripts:` section ? just `configScripts: ./jenkins.yaml` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was able to add as job like below,

```
jobs:
Test-Job: |-
  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
  <project>
    <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
    <properties/>
    <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
    <canRoam>false</canRoam>
    <disabled>false</disabled>
    <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
    <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
    <triggers/>
    <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
    <builders/>
    <publishers/>
    <buildWrappers/>
  </project>
```

Comment: what's the hierarchy of this? does this go under the configScripts? or same level?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `job DSL` plugin which allows you to pass a Jenkins pipeline in a cleaner looking fashion. Your code would look like this:

```
    installPlugins:
      ... << all your other plugins >>
      - job-dsl:1.77
      ...
    JCasC:
      configScripts: 
        base-config: |-
          ... << your other plugin config >>
          jobs:
            - script: >
                pipelineJob('unit-tests') {
                  << your pipeline config >>
                }
                ...
```

Check out the example in JCasC [demo](https://github.com/jenkinsci/configuration-as-code-plugin/blob/master/demos/jobs/pipeline.yaml).
One more thing to add, once you've added the jobDSL plugin there's an API endpoint available on your Jenkins implementation at: https://your-jenkins-url/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html, it provides detailed description of all the params you can set for each jobDSL method.